# Getting OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to use flickrapi in flask on mac osx

Tags: macos, flask, flickr

I've setup a flask app on my mac and am trying to return data from the flickrapi (stuvel) to a page. I can run flickrapi functions successfully from command line. However, when flask tries, I get an internal 500 error which the logs show as being:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/WebServer/.flickr'
```

Doing some searching, I found the the user running my script with flask has insufficient permissions. Whereas the user at the command line has sufficient permissions.

So, i got it working by editing my apache's conf file, and switching httpd to run as the same user and group as my command line, instead of "_www"

...Now... is this going to give me trouble later? Will I run into this when I deploy to a live server?

And finally, why is a ".flickr" file being created in OSX's default web server folder, as opposed to the folder I have set up for my development site via my virtual host settings? I suspect that if this file was being placed in the correct folder, this would not be a problem. Is that an flickrapi setting? Flask setting?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For me location of this folder should be configurable.

I have created issue for that: https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/flickrapi/issues/68

You can disable this option by setting: `store_token=False`

```
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(self.KEY, self.SECRET, format='parsed-json', store_token=False)
```